# React native failed to upgrade : fatal: working tree '.' already exists

Tags: react-native, upgrade

I tried to upgrade react native version from 0.41 to 0.44 using these [instructions](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2016/12/05/easier-upgrades.html), but I got this error :

```
error Command failed.
Exit code: 128
Command: git
Arguments: clone https://github.com/lwansbrough/react-native-camera.git /Users/abdelnacer/Library/Caches/Yarn/v1/.tmp/264e7f98ae7b8a32797877705f218964
Directory: /Users/abdelnacer/work/react/DuluxTradePoints
Output:
fatal: working tree '.' already exists.
git-upgrade ERR! An error occurred during upgrade: 
git-upgrade ERR! Error: Command 'yarn add react-native@0.42.0' exited with code 1:
stderr: undefinederror Command failed.
Exit code: 128
Command: git
Arguments: clone https://github.com/lwansbrough/react-native-camera.git /Users/abdelnacer/Library/Caches/Yarn/v1/.tmp/264e7f98ae7b8a32797877705f218964
Directory: /Users/abdelnacer/work/react/DuluxTradePoints
Output:
fatal: working tree '.' already exists.

stdout: yarn add v0.24.5
[1/4] Resolving packages...
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.

    at ChildProcess.child.on.code (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-git-upgrade/cliEntry.js:58:18)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:194:7)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:12) 
git-upgrade ERR! Restore initial sources 
Note: checking out 'project-snapshot'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

  git checkout -b <new-branch-name>

HEAD is now at 4c8828d... Project snapshot
```

May be someone have any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried several `yarn` + `react-native-git-upgrade` but it didn't work for me

To make the upgrade work I had to remove the node_modules and clean the yarn cache too.

**1) Remove node_modules**:

```
rm -rf ./node_modules
```

**2) Clean yarn cache**

```
rm -rf /Users/<myUsername>/Library/Caches/Yarn/v1/.tmp

yarn cache clean
```

I am not sure if it would have worked with running just the removal of `.tmp`

**3) Run** `yarn`

**4) Run upgrade again**

```
react-native-git-upgrade
```

Note: My upgrade was from 0.51.0 to 0.53.3

Comment: I had the same issue. Deleting the `node_modules` did it for me. Upgrading from `0.54.4` to `0.55.4` on macOS 10.13

Answer (score 1):

facing the same issue,

try to run

```
yarn
```

then

```
react-native-git-upgrade
```

or

it might help you :

> https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11578#issuecomment-278022460